# How can I input data into (parentheses) of an output

Tags: python, sqlite

I have printed an output such as:

```
enable
configure terminal
interface fa(fanumber)/(fanumber)
ip adress (ip) (subnet mask) 
no shutdown
```

And I would like to input new data in all the parentheses:

In my example these would be:

```
(fanumber)/(fanumber)
(ip) (subnet mask)
```

Do I need to write more code in my current function or write a new function?

How can I do this?

My current function is:

```
def readciscodevice(function, device):
            conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
            cur = conn.cursor()
            if device == "switch":
                    cur.execute(
                            "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",
                            (function,))
                    read = cur.fetchall()
                    return read
            elif device == "router":
                    cur.execute(
                            "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM router WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",
                            (function,))
                    read = cur.fetchall()
                    return read;
            elif device == "showcommand":
                cur.execute(
                        "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM showcommand WHERE   function =? or  function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",
                        (function,))
                read = cur.fetchall()
                return read;



    a = input("function:")
    b = input("device:")
    for result in readciscodevice(a,b):
            print(result[0])
```

I am not asking for you to rewrite my function. I am just seeking help to fix the parentheses () problem.

Thank you

Update:
Do I need to use replace() to do my function?

More update:
maybe i did not explain my question clearly. I would like to re-input my data into my output to make it from:

```
interface fa(fanumber)/(fanumber)
ip adress (ip) (subnet mask)
```

into

```
interface fa0/1
ip adress 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: The values currently referred to as 'fanumber' before and after the / are two distinct values... ex: fa0/1, fa1/1 or fa1/24.  Also 'adress' needs to be spelled 'address' or the command will fail'.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I completely understand your problem, but to find anything in a text that is in between parenthesis, you could try the following:

```
import re
p = re.compile('\(.*?\)')
iterator = p.finditer('I (want) to (capture) some (words) in (parenthesis)')
for match in iterator:
    print(match.group())
```

output:

```
(want)
(capture)
(words)
(parenthesis)
```

Note however that this won't work very well once your parenthesized words can be nested (e.g 'some (words in (parenthesis))'). Also, it won't capture the division character in your example. Guess you'd have to write some exceptions/a more sophisticated regex to capture some mathematical operators as well then.

update:

```
iterator = p.finditer(s)
for match in iterator:
    s = s[:match.start()] + [match.start():match.end()].replace(match.group(), dict[match.group()]) + s[match.end()]
```

Comment: @lgor thank you for your suggestion! Maybe i did not explain my word clearly. I would like to reinput data in interface fa(fanumber)/(fanumber)
ip adress (ip) (subnet mask)  and make the result to be fa0/1 ip address 192.168.1.1(<<this is ip) 255.255.255.0(<<this is subnet mask)

Comment: Ah, oke. In that case I assume you have a dictionary mapping 'subnet mask' to 255.255.255.0 (and some keys for ip address, etc.). The match you'll find in the iterator also has a start and end, so I'd try something like this (haven't tested it, if some admin could tell me how to properly display code in comments, that would be great!) 
iterator = p.finditer(s); for match in iterator: s = s[:match.start()] + s[match.start():match.end()].replace(match.group(), dict[match.group()]) + s[match.end()]

Comment: Thanks; Updated again. Looking at it again, I suspect that this may not be exactly what you want and it may end up only replacing the last match found in iterator. But if I were to solve your problem, I would go along these lines at least.

Comment: @lgor i am going to update again as I cant run your code as these following problem and now I am trying to solve it too.